# How to install PhantomJS in R Studio?

Tags: r, phantomjs

I wrote a program that needs to run, the following is my R code:

```
library(webshot)

webshot("tmp.html","Normal_top100.png", delay =10, vwidth = 1920, vheight=1080)
```

However, I got the following message:

`PhantomJS not found. You can install it with webshot::install_phantomjs(). If it is installed, please make sure the phantomjs executable can be found via the PATH variable.`

Therefore, I need to install Phantomjs, but I got some problem cannot be solved.

I saw the following link to install it, but I don't know why I still cannot run successfully.

`https://www.jianshu.com/p/a7fd378714eb`

The website said that you need to set Environment Variable and I used the method of this link. However, when I run this code again, I still got the same error. I suspected the reason is this website is incorrect.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: So did you run `webshot::install_phantomjs()`? What exactly happened? Or did you install phantomjs some other way? What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 10, so I need to enter ```webshot::install_phantomjs()``` in Console of R Studio?
I used the tutorial link to install it and I use .exe file to install. I think It is a normal method.

Comment: That’s an R command you would enter in the console in RStudio.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I tried it successfully. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

For installing phantomJS you just need to run the following command in the R console:

```
webshot::install_phantomjs()
```

It will be downloaded and installed into your default library directory.

For more details please read the documentation:
https://rdrr.io/cran/webshot/man/install_phantomjs.html